# how to calculate the total value of orders on each day where we have the time in date (it doesn't do the SUM function)? SQL ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle

I am struggling with the time in order_date column. I deleted the time from date format (order_date) but THE SUM doesn't calculate the result. Let's say that we have 3 orders (20$, 15$,10$) in 1st Jul 2022 and it doesn't show the result 45$. It shows 3 line for 1st July 2022.I suspected that time influenced the solution which I would like to achieve.
PS I set the data for discount number is 1 - function WHERE

```
SELECT
    TO_CHAR(ORDER_DATE, 'DD/MM/YYYY'),
    SUM(order_total) as total
FROM
    oe.orders
WHERE promotion_id = 1
GROUP BY order_date;
```

I cut the time in date column (order_date) and I can't move on.

2ND QUESTION
If I would like to add the second discount (WHERE promotion_id = 1 or promotion_id = 2) and after I need to sum up the amount for separate discounts (promotion_id = 1 & 2). How could I calculate this?

Comment: try grouping by date instead of datetime: `GROUP BY TO_CHAR(ORDER_DATE, 'DD/MM/YYYY')`

Comment: oh it was easier then I thought. Thank you very much!

Comment: To elaborate, The is because you're grouping on ORDER_DATE, however this may also include a timestamp, therefore when it groups, unless all 3 orders are the same date _AND TIME_ it will see them as seperate entries.  Doing as Vvdl explains above will cast the date to a "Date Only" format and rectify the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Could you use the `trunc` function to remove the time part of the `order_date` column before grouping the records by date?

Like:

```
SELECT
    TRUNC(order_date) AS order_date,
    SUM(order_total) as total
FROM
    oe.orders
WHERE promotion_id = 1
GROUP BY TRUNC(order_date);
```